# New VSTS Nuget Task: No Option "IncludeReferencedProjects"

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a VSTS build process which was using the Nuget Packager and Nuget Publisher tasks. Those are now deprecated. I've upgraded to the newer Nuget task, but there isn't an option to "Include Referenced Projects".  Is there another way to do this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the "Pack Options" section and click the (i) to display the informational pop-up. At the bottom of the pop-up is a "Link". Click "Link" to get another pop-up with the options for whichever field you click to get the (i) pop-up. However, you can also scroll through that list to see all the available options, and to set them, even if the option does not appear on the screen anywhere.